# How to define an OnClick event handler for a button from within Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, button, event-handling, onclick, qt-creator

In visual studio, when designing a windows form, I can easily add an OnClick event handler for a button by double clicking on it. Is it possible to do the same in QtCreator? How should I handle the Click event of a button? Is manually writing the required code from scratch the only option?

Comment: Are you aware of the SIGNALS and SLOTs schema in Qt? Sounds like that's what you want.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In the designer,

1. add Push Button to the form
2. right click the Push Button
3. select "Go to slot..."
4. select "clicked()" signal
5. done

The terms are different from .NET, so in this case we are talking about signals and slots, and the signal emitted when QPushButton is clicked is called `clicked()` instead of `OnClick`.

Reading the [Qt's documentation about signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/signalsandslots.html) is recommended.

Comment: Pretty intuitive I would say. Expected to do 2-4 by double click.

Comment: pretty. Thanks so much!

Comment: No "Go to slot.." for me, I had to go to to menu: view -> signal/slot editor

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. So, I clicked "clicked()" at "signal", some sort of class in "receiver" but how do I make my handler method show up there? FWIW, where do I actually put it? I can't find that receiver class anywhere. It seems to be some autogenerated stuff.

Comment: no "Go to slot..." option

Answer (score 8):

#### In header file:

```
private slots:
    void exit_app();
```

#### in xyz.cpp:

```
connect(ui.button_name, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(exit_app()));
```

#### define the exit_app() func that SLOT calls.

```
void QtTest2::exit_app()
{
    QApplication::exit();
}
```