# Search PDF In Qt C++ in QPDFView

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qpdf

I want to **Search Words in PDF File** in my Qt C++ Application. I am using Qt 6.4.1
widget, `QPDFView` class, and `QPdfSearchModel`, and I don't know what the syntax is.
As input I am taking in LineEdit Signal from PushButton.

```
void MainWindow::SearchString(const QUrl &docLocation)
{
    //*m_document="/home/droid/12.pdf".toLocalFile();
    auto nav = ui->pdfView->pageNavigator();
   //QString res;
  //  res= QString searchString(text);
    //auto navs=ui->pdfView->searchString(text);
//QString find=ui->pdfView->find(text);
//void res;
QString text;

text=ui->lineEdit->text();
QString file=docLocation.toLocalFile();

    QPdfSearchModel *search=new QPdfSearchModel(this);
   search->setDocument(m_document->);//Problem???
```

This is my appLication Widget:
[image: My application Widget]

I have used Pdf Search Model but don't know the syntax to use with my application.
Path of my pdf is Stored in `const &Qurl docLocation`.

Comment: maybe QPdfSearchModel class can help here : https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpdfsearchmodel.html

Comment: Yes Iam  using The class you Mention But what is the Syntax take input text from line edit on clicking Button i go the respective page Thank You!!

Comment: if you want the search to happen when the user clicks on the button then some 'event handling' has to be put in for the click button event. Please have a look at how event handling works in Qt. hint : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041876/how-to-define-an-onclick-event-handler-for-a-button-from-within-qt-creator
OR
https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_QPushButton